# IE9: Option to disable autocomplete in forms is disabled/greyed out in IE9 options

Tags: internet-explorer-9, autocomplete

In IE9, I went to Tools > Options > [Content] > AutoComplete Settings to uncheck the Forms checkbox so IE would no longer save data I enter into forms, but it's checked and disabled which means I can't uncheck it. Any idea why this would be?

Comment: Is this a company computer? Possibly on a Domain?

Comment: Yes, it's my company computer and it's on a domain.  What are my options?

Answer (score 3):

Since this is a company computer on a domain, there's a good chance the IT staff have set up Group Policies to control the features of various parts of Windows and/or IE.

You will have to speak with someone in IT who can adjust this for you (or explain why it's not allowed).

It may be an unexpected side-effect of a setting that performed differently in previous IE versions.

I'm not sure which GPO would affect this particular setting (Is it ONLY the "Forms" that unavailable?), but there are options for AutoComplete in the GP for both Computer and User levels under their respective `Windows Components\Internet Explorer\Internet Settings\AutoComplete` sections.

Perhaps try and run `rsop.msc` (Resultant Set of Policies) and it should show you which policies are currently in effect for you and your computer.

Answer (score -1):

I believe this is the key:
http://www.boyce.us/gp/gpcontent.asp?ID=720

Is there anyway to use local admin rights to re-enable the autocomplete on forms/usernames and passwords?  That particuler key doesnt exist and I am not sure what it should look like/contain:

HKLM\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Restrictions!FormSuggest Passwords

Thanks!

Comment: Hi solomani, Welcome to the site! If you have a question, please don't put it in the 'answer' of another question, Instead, why not propose your own question? - there is a button near the top-right hand side of the page

Comment: Apologies!  My mistake!  Will do.

Comment: No problem, it's an easy mistake to make :)